# I can not get it to display info by month. Is it the GROUP BY or my LOOP that's messed up?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

I need to display the amount of money used by each PAYMENTMETHOD by MONTH.

EXAMPLE:

```
    JANUARY RENTALS
         CASH    $300
         VISA    $200
    TOTAL: $500
```

I have tried many different GROUP BY statements and I have tried DISTINCT, but I keep getting the error "NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION".
The code (without a GROUP BY expression) displays a long list that repeats the same months. I do not know for sure if the problem is even the GROUP BY or if it's how I have the LOOP set up.

NOTE: All of the data is from the same year, but the date is in the format of 16-DEC-04
This is the code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NameMonth (MonthNum INT) 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
        Month_Name VARCHAR2(9) := 'Default';
    BEGIN
        CASE
        WHEN MonthNum = 1 THEN  Month_Name := 'January';
        WHEN MonthNum = 2 THEN  Month_Name := 'February';
        WHEN MonthNum = 3 THEN  Month_Name := 'March';
        WHEN MonthNum = 4 THEN  Month_Name := 'April';
        WHEN MonthNum = 5 THEN  Month_Name := 'May';
        WHEN MonthNum = 6 THEN  Month_Name := 'June';
        WHEN MonthNum = 7 THEN  Month_Name := 'July';
        WHEN MonthNum = 8 THEN  Month_Name := 'August';
        WHEN MonthNum = 9 THEN  Month_Name := 'September';
        WHEN MonthNum = 10 THEN  Month_Name := 'October';
        WHEN MonthNum = 11 THEN  Month_Name := 'November';
        WHEN MonthNum = 12 THEN  Month_Name := 'December';
        END CASE;

        RETURN Month_Name;
    END;
 /   

 DECLARE 
    CURSOR cNameOfMonth IS
        SELECT NameMonth(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM RENTAL.RENTDATE)) AS RentMonth, RENTAL.PAYMENTMETHOD, RENTITEM.RENTFEE
        FROM ALLPOWDER.RENTAL, ALLPOWDER.RENTITEM
        WHERE RENTAL.RENTID = RENTITEM.RENTID
        GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM RENTAL.RENTDATE) 
   -- I've also tried NameMonth(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM RENTAL.RENTDATE)) and just RENTAL.RENTDATE
        ORDER BY RentMonth;

    Rental_Rec cNameOfMonth%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN cNameOfMonth;
    LOOP
        FETCH cNameOfMonth INTO Rental_Rec;
        EXIT WHEN cNameOfMonth%NOTFOUND;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Rental_Rec.RentMonth || ' Rentals ----------------');
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cNameOfMonth;
END; 
/
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query with proper `JOIN` syntax and table aliases.  The problem columns are identified:

```
    SELECT NameMonth(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM R.RENTDATE)) AS RentMonth,
           R.PAYMENTMETHOD, RI.RENTFEE
-----------^  --------------^
    FROM ALLPOWDER.RENTAL R JOIN
         ALLPOWDER.RENTITEM RI
         ON R.RENTID = RI.RENTID
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM R.RENTDATE) 
    ORDER BY RentMonth;
```

It is quite unclear what you want to do.  You have `GROUP BY` with no aggregation functions, so that is suspicious.  Some possibilities:

- You don't intend an aggregation query.  So remove `GROUP BY`.
- You want one row per month.  Use aggregation functions on the other columns.
- You want one row per month and payment method.  Use an aggregation function on `RENTFEE`.
- Something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your function to translate month number to month name is unnecessary, and you're not generating a total. I suspect you wanted something like:

```
SELECT INITCAP(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(r.RENTDATE, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH')) AS RENTMONTH,
       INITCAP(r.PAYMENTMETHOD) AS PAYMENTMETHOD,
       SUM(i.RENTFEE) AS TOTAL_RENTFEE
  FROM ALLPOWDER.RENTAL r
  INNER JOIN ALLPOWDER.RENTITEM i
    ON i.RENTID = r.RENTID
  GROUP BY TRUNC(r.RENTDATE, 'MONTH'),
           r.PAYMENTMETHOD
  ORDER BY TRUNC(r.RENTDATE, 'MONTH')
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b583101b91c346b5df47c779fe799f30)